# Modifying For loop variables cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Thing I want to do is to filter out specific video file extensions from a text file containing various video file names e.g filename.txt contents are

```
Red.mp4
Yellow.mp4
Blue.mp4
Orange.wmv
Purple.wmv
```

Now I will parse this file for .mp4 only & utilise 'for parameter' to make **several** .txt files each containing particular code for a particular file. In other words will create number of files same as number of .mp4 video in filename.txt My code

```
::==
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type filename.txt ^|findstr ".mp4"') do (
set /a n+=1
echo >myfile!n!.txt
set v!n!=x264 --crf 23  --level 3.1 --tune film --o "%%a" "%%a.mkv"
)
set v
pause
::==
```

I have **two** problems:

1. How do I **modify** %%a to have its .mp4 string removed because when I apply "%%a.mkv" a file will be named *.mp4.mkv and I don't want that and .mp4 can be typed manually like --o "%%a.mp4" "%%a.mkv"
2. Provided that required txt files are already created how do I pass variables v1,v2,v3... to its respective text file I tried with

   echo %v!n!% > >myfile!n!.txt
   **within** loop but it didn't work, so plz advice

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any need to create an array of variables with one loop, and then add the content to files in a 2nd loop. Simply do everything in one loop.

Also, there is no need to create an empty file, and your attempt to do so is incorrect - it adds the line `ECHO is off.` to each file. To echo a blank line you should use `>filename ECHO(`. To create an empty file use `copy nul filename`.

This is unlikely to be a concern, but it is possible for a filename to contain `!`. Expansion of a FOR variable containing `!` will be corrupted if delayed expansion is enabled. The issue can be solved by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop, but there is another solution: use another FINDSTR command to prepend each line with the line number, and then parse the line number and file name with the FOR loop. This eliminates the need to increment a counter and eliminates the need for delayed expansion.

The `~n` FOR variable modifier is used to get the name without the extension.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr /lie ".mp4" filename.txt^|findstr /n "^"'
) do (
  >"myfile%%A.txt" echo x264 --crf 23 --level 3.1 --tune film --o "%%B" "%%~nB.mkv"
)
```

Comment: I'd recommend `echo.>filename`for echoing blank lines. It's easier to read than the alternatives.